# HTML Element overflow CSS property

Tags: html, css

Assume an element is scrollable and its' content overflows the parent. Is there a CSS property that improves rendering performance or avoid side effects?

Look at the example image below. The "blue" div in chrome shows the overflowed content with the "READ MORE" button which will expand the content. "blue" div is out of the "white" container div.

Can I apply a class when the content is collapsed to instruct the browser to  ignore the content in the blue div?

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClWgc.png)

Comment: Assuming the overflowing content is contained inside the top main div, you could simply apply a `z-index` lower than the bottom part (orange), so then the bottom part will always show on top of the content that you wan to hide, as soon as the tab "read more" expands, the blue part will be shown as you want. That's just a workaround.

Comment: It works fine as it is but I'm just showing that while inspecting the blue div, it overflows the white parent container... I'd expect it to be cut-off by the parent since it is not on screen. Do you follow me?

Comment: Then try to use JS and tell the blue div to have a respective `height` value while the "read more" isn't clicked, and as the link is clicked, the div resizes back to its original height.

Comment: yeah using JS is valid too ... but i was specifically looking for a CSS property .. it may not be an issue other than chrome devtools inspector showing it... I was just curious if it was something that could or needs to be addressed